# biblatex: Different formatting for citations v. bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I'm using the `authoryear` style, and am obliged to format the authors' names as normal text at the point of citation, but in small caps in the bibliography. Here's my first, simpleton's MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{memoir}
% ----------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[%
    style=authoryear,
    bibstyle=authoryear,
    firstinits=true,
    backend=biber,
]{biblatex}
% ----------------------------------------------------------
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
% ----------------------------------------------------------
\addbibresource{biblatex-nature.bib}
\addbibresource{caliente-bib.bib}
\nocite{*}
% ----------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\parencite{AkcelikBirosGhattasLongVanBloemenWaanders2003}

% ==========================================================
\raggedright
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Now, that half works; the author names in the bibliography are in small caps, but, unfortunately, so is the citation in the text (rendered approximately):

> (AKCELIK, BIROS, GHATTAS, et al. 2003)

Am I tinkering in the right place? Is there some simple way I can test, in `\mkbibxxx`, whether I'm in the text or in the bibliography? Should I look elsewhere? Can I hope for a "simple" solution??

Environment: TeXLive 2011+, latexmk, biblatex 2011/07/29 v1.6, biber 0.9.5

`caliente-bib.bib` is [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~caliente/caliente-bib-bib.html). I don't remember why I used this...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\AtBeginBibliography{% 
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}%
}
```

In addition: The `style` package option covers both `bibstyle` and `citestyle`, so `bibstyle=authoryear` is superfluous in your example. Also, consider to use the higher-level command `\autocite` instead of `\parencite`; this way, you may switch to foonote citations by simply declaring `autocite=footnote`.

Comment: Thanks! +1+\checkmark. Worth another +1 for the additional advice, too.

Answer (score 3):

Note: As of March 2016 (biblatex 3.3), you need to change `\mkbibnamefamily` instead of `\mkbibnamelast`

Comment: I think this would be better suited as a comment and not a new answer in its own right. See also [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864).

Comment: Sorry, yes. However, I don't have reputation on tex, only on stackoverflow (seems not to be linked). Thanks very much for the link!!