# Different bibstyles for bibentry vs. bibliography

Tags: natbib, bibentry

Using `natbib`, `bibentry`. I would like if possible to render the bibentries in a different style than that in the Bibliography section in the end.

A particularity with this is that bibentry copies verbatim the style used for the entire bibliography and with the `bst`s like that of `savetrees.bst` (my case) or `IEEEtran.bst` or the like it creates a problem. Specifically, the repeated author(s) across two or more bib items that follow each other are replaced with a long dash `---` except for the first bib item in such a sequence. When I use a `\bibentry` for some of these in the main body the dash is preserved, whereas I need the author(s) name(s) in the case of `\bibentry` while keeping it as it is in Bibliography with the dash.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc
{
  death-star,
  author       = {Bevel Lemelisk and Wilhuff Tarkin and Darth Vader and Darth Sidious},
  title        = {{Death Star}},
  howpublished = {Alderaan and Yavin 4},
  year         = {0 BBY}
}
@misc
{
  death-star-2,
  author       = {Bevel Lemelisk and Wilhuff Tarkin and Darth Vader and Darth Sidious},
  title        = {{Death Star II}},
  howpublished = {Endor},
  year         = {4 ABY}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
They first built~\cite{death-star}.

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \textbf{Have:}\\
\bibentry{death-star-2}
  \item \textbf{Need:}\\
B. Lemelisk, W. Tarkin, D. Vader, and D. Sidious, ``Death Star II,'' Endor, 4 ABY
\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[2]

%\bibliographystyle{savetrees}
\bibliographystyle{IEEETran}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have to use `natbib`?  This is probably easier to do with `biblatex`.

Comment: @AlanMunn There was a reason I had to switch to `natbib`; IIRC for doi rendering and maybe something else. I am using `bibtex`. I guess I never took time to investigate `biblatex`---how can it be of help in this situation? I thought that'd a style question than a bib backend?

Comment: @AlanMunn Ah, I think you mean the **package** `biblatex` as described in [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30908/biblatex-different-formatting-for-citations-v-bibliography)?

Comment: @serguei For an overview of the differences, see: [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701) `biblatex` is very powerful and unless you are committed to using `natbib` because of journal requirements, it's probably worth looking into.

Comment: @Alan Yeah, I've read it, thanks. It seems I can't immediately switch to `biblatex` just yet. While it's not for a journal right now, but a thesis, a simple naive attempt to switch generated a few errors and a whole bunch of warnings and no bibliography produced :( Looks like there is some conflict with existing (plenty) packages I am using. Plus, I am using existing `.bst`s and need a classical `.bbl` as well. I also have a lot of bib items in my `.bib`. I am under extreme crunch time at the moment to devote time to debug it, so I will have to let `biblatex` option go for now.

Comment: I guess no one has an answer to this. What would be a `biblatex` solution to this?