# How to make the surnames of the authors appear in capital letters in Natbib?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, small-caps, capitalization

I'm using the code seen below and I'm trying to make the surnames of the authors appear in capital letters (with the first letter in large caps and the following letters in small caps), as seen in the pictures attached.

This is what I want:

[image]

and this is what I'm getting:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{natbib}
 \bibliographystyle{chicago2}

\begin{document}

 \cite{picallo1990modal} 

\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you forced to use `natbib`? This is much easier to do if you use `biblatex`. (Unrelated, but you need to put `Catalan` in `{...}` to preserve its capitalization.)

Comment: I'm just worried about the surname. Can you show me how to make this using biblatex? I know that catalan must be put between {}

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30908/2693.

Comment: Many thanks for this, but it's not working. I have the bibliography written manually as desired. Is there a way to use the citation commands in the text without generating (printing) the bibliography at the end, which I will be adding manually?

Comment: I’m not quite sure I understand what you’re doing then. But if you comment out the `\printbibliography` command in a `biblatex` document the citations will show up but the bibliography won’t be produced.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!

Comment: Is the `chicago2` bib style available online? If so, where?